# using geom_boxplot for grouped box plot on continues data makes NA label

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using `geom_boxplot` with `ggplot` and I want to have grouped box plot. when I use it for continues numerical data with grouping(`fill` and `group`) it makes NA labels for all but the first factor.
here is an example data:

```
    d<- data.table(a=c(11,1,2,3,8,4,9,12,50,7), b= c(1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,4,4), 
d=as.factor(c("e","f", "e","e","e","f","f","e","f","f")))
ggplot(d, mapping=aes(x=b,y=a,fill= d)) + geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(b, 2)))
```

this will produces boxplot bins with group labels f and NA instead of f and e.
this is just a toy example. I am in general looking for any example of making grouped boxplot on continues data with adjusted bin size.
I really appreciate your help to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you add some details on what the final graphic should look like?  Not with the labels, but how many boxes you are hoping to have and where they should be plotted.

Comment: I expect to have 4 boxes (2 bins x 2 labels), locating ideally at the center of the bins.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the labeling issue lies with how `cut_width` acts upon the data. It places the data in column `b` into bins with your specified width of 2. So in the example data you provided, two bins exist: [b=1, b=3] and (b=3, b=5].

Bin 1, [b=1, b=3], contains rows 1-8 in your data.table `d`. This means that this bin contains data from two factor levels, `e , f` from column `d`. Since the bin has two factor levels, it cannot classified as either `e` or `f` and it receives a value of `NA` in the legend.

Bin 2, (b=3, b=5], contains rows 9 and 10 in your data.table `d`. It contains only data from factor level `f` in column `d` and so it is labelled `f` in the legend.

In this instance, your legend labels should be `f`, and `e&f` which you could set manually with

```
ggplot(d, mapping=aes(x=b,y=a,fill= d)) + geom_boxplot(aes(group=cut_width(b,2)))+scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("f", "e&f"))
```

Hope this helps to clear up the issue!

Comment: Yes exactly I know that in Bin 1 I have both e and f lables and I want to have grouped box_plot. meaning that showing box plot of each lable separately next to each other.

Comment: If you are specifying the `cut_width()` width and center arguments, you can determine which rows of your data will fall into the bins beforehand and then create legend labels for those bins and pass them in manually. E.g. `which(d[, "b"] >=1 & d[, "b"] <=3)` will give you the rows in the bin. You know the bins are of width 2 and begin at the center you specified, so you can continue along with the next bin `which(d[, "b"] >3 & d[, "b"] <=5)` etc... Get the factors in each bin and then make your own legend labels. You could create a new col "g", `cbind` it to `d` and then set the fill="g".

Comment: Where the new column "g" contains the newly created legend labels or factor levels of each bin.

Comment: my real data is very big so I prefer to not to do it manually.

Comment: A programmatic solution exists using the same methodology I suggested above. It doesn't need to all be manual. Just a thought